# Exception thrown at predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

I don't know why am I getting an error on that piece of code:

```
 //fecha y hora actual


        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
        let hour = components.hour
        let minutes = components.minute
        let year = components.year
        let month = components.month
        let day = components.day
        print (year)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "year_created >= %@", year)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

The exception is thrown at line:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "year_created >= %@", year)
```

where "year_created" is a int16 core data attribute.

Any help is welcome.

SCREENSHOT added:

[image]

Comment: Could you paste here description of the exception?

Comment: @JakubKnejzlik, there is not description at all. But I will paste a screenshot of Xcode after the exception is thrown, may be it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for screenshot. My guess is that it's not exactly the NSPredicate problem. Try to change code to this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "year_created >= %ld", year)
```

NSDateComponent's year property is NSInteger, so you can't use %@ in format.